# attempting to manually download MNIST pytorch dataset in databricks

Tags: pytorch, databricks, torchvision

I've attempted a couple different iterations now to get the dataset manually loaded into databricks's DBFS.. so that PyTorch can load it.. however the MNIST dataset seems to just be some binary file.. is it expected I unzip it first or just.. point to the GZipped tarball?  So far all my trials have gotten this error

```
 train_dataset = datasets.MNIST(
     13     'dbfs:/FileStore/tarballs/train_images_idx3_ubyte.gz',
     14     train=True,
```

```
RuntimeError: Dataset not found. You can use download=True to download it
```

I am aware I can turn `Download=True` , however due to the firewalls this is not an option and I want to just upload the files and wire them in myself via DBFS... anyone done this as well?

EDIT:  @alexey suggested I need to add the extra paths `MNIST/raw`

[image]

And then change the input to

```
  train_dataset = datasets.MNIST(
    '/dbfs/FileStore/tarballs',
    train=True,
    download=False,
    transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))]))
  data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
```

But same error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My code and dir:

```
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    datasets.MNIST('../colabx/data', train=True, download=False,
                   transform=transforms.Compose([
                       transforms.ToTensor(),
                       transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))

....\colabx\data\MNIST\raw>ls
t10k-images-idx3-ubyte     train-images-idx3-ubyte
t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz  train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte     train-labels-idx1-ubyte
t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz  train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
```

Comment: hi @alexey , am I reading correctly.. I need to put it in subdirs MNIST/RAW then ? let me try that thank you

Comment: update: Unfortunately this still didn't work.. will keep trying

Comment: Well, then I don't know.

Comment: works just fine if you have correct folder structure

Comment: @AlexOtt based on what I am placing in the post.. I've added all necessary files to the necessary folder structure.. tried both `dbfs:/...` as well as `/dbfs/...`

Comment: The issue in my case was in _deceivingly_ similar file names. While uploading files to DBFS via Databricks Web UI, dashes in file names had been automatically converted to underscores, which made visual detection difficult and prevented torch to locate necessary resources.

For example, `train-images-idx3-ubyte` was converted to `train_images_idx3_ubyte`.